# How to restore\unfold multiindex in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

I am very close to go insane. I have a dataframe like this:

```
subject  sessionIndex  screenIndex  index      key    time
   s019             1            3      1    Shift  0.3442
   s019             1            3      2  Shift.t  0.1514
   s019             1            3      3        h  0.0844
   s019             1            3      4        e  0.1127
   s019             1            3      5    space  0.1201
   s091             3            5    821        h  0.1126
   s091             3            5    822        a  0.1425
   s091             3            5    823        n  0.0926
   s091             3            5    824        d  0.1525
```

after using:

```
pivot_table(data,values='time', rows=['subject','sessionIndex','screenIndex','index'], cols=['key'])
```

I have the following dataframe:

```
key                                      Shift  Shift.t       a       d   ...
subject sessionIndex screenIndex index                                    
s019    1            3           1      0.3442      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...
                                 2         NaN   0.1514     NaN     NaN   ...
                                 3         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...
                                 4         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...
                                 5         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...
s091    3            5           821       NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...
                                 822       NaN      NaN  0.1425     NaN   ...
                                 823       NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...
                                 824       NaN      NaN     NaN  0.1525   ...
```

That is great but I got stuck to "unfold" the multiindex so that my dataframe looks like this:

```
subject sessionIndex screenIndex index   Shift  Shift.t       a       d   ...                               
s019    1            3           1      0.3442      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...
s019    1            3           2         NaN   0.1514     NaN     NaN   ...
s019    1            3           3         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...
s019    1            3           4         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...
s019    1            3           5         NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...
s091    3            5           821       NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...
s091    3            5           822       NaN      NaN  0.1425     NaN   ...
s091    3            5           823       NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...
s091    3            5           824       NaN      NaN     NaN  0.1525   ...
```

I already tried reindexing and index reset. I am fairly new to pandas and python so maybe I am just to stupid. Please let me know what I am missing here, Thx.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "unfold". Although repeating indicies are hidden for display purposes, they are still there. But perhaps you wish the four MultiIndex level were normal columns -- in which case they would display as you specified and would in some ways be easier to handle. In that case, just use the result of ``df.reset_index()``.

Comment: Hi Dan, thx for your reply. I already tried this. The issue is that this command also reverts all the variables back into cases. So my data is as before I called pivot_table.

Comment: Hmm. That's surprising. Are you sure you are executing reset_index on the result of pivot_table, and not on the original DataFrame?

Comment: I am going nuts. It looks you are right. I added a temporary variable to store the results of pivot_table and now it seem to work! Big THX would never figure this out alone!

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a display option in pandas.

Try adding this line immediately after importing pandas:
`pandas.set_printoptions(multi_sparse=False)`

Comment: Hi Paul, thx for your reply. My problem is actually not the formatting. I want to use the columns to execute some selectors. This is much harder when the columns are joined in an multiindex. Therfore I want to restore the index columns.

Comment: @user2675976 It's better to keep the index, IMO. The `dataframe.select` method can very powerfully execute selections on multiply values of a `MultiIndex` (e.g., `subset = df.select(lambda x: x[0] == 'S019' and s[2] in [3,5] and s[3] <= 5)`

Comment: Thx Paul. I solved my issue. As I wanted to use different selection criterias afterwards:  train = data[data['subject']==user] 
 train = train[train['sessionIndex']==1]
it seems easier to restore the inices.